# A strange scenario in anaconda, in Spyder -- I saw a console named history.py and I could NOT create a new console

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, console, spyder

Software info:
Windows 11. When strange scenarios occurs, I did NOT used with VM (virtual machine). But I have created some VM boxes.

Hardware info:
[a figure illustrates my currently used device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4tjo.jpg)

Here is a figure illustrates my currently used device.
I use notebook with MSI.

Occur in the app:
Spyder which is a subset of Anaconda Navigator.

Issue:
[a figure to my strange scenarios]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JQfz.jpg)

I first met this issue.
I met strange scenarios in anaconda, in Spyder --
I saw a console named history.py and I could NOT create a new console.

Can anyone tell me why?

Any replies to the solution will be grateful.

Things I have tried (respectively).

1.I have tried to restart the Spyder and Anaconda Navigator.

2.Then I have tried to restart my notebook.

3. Browse some posts at issue tracker of Anaconda Navigator.

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues

But the issue is NOT solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved although I don't know why the issue occurred.

Suggested by the website:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/5193

I used the following command in Anaconda Prompt:

```
spyder --reset
```

And it was successful:

[image: reset spyder]

Then I restarted Spyder, and the issue disappeared:

[image: restart Spyder]

Answer (score 0):

I ensure why it happens.

There were crashes which are caused by the infinite recursive call at runtime.

When I ran the code, it also crashed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).